# angular 2 seed, webstorm 2016.1 suddenly stop importing libraries

Tags: import, angular, webstorm, node-modules

I'm using the newest Webstorm 2016.1 und angular 2 seed.

Somehow it doesn't auto import libraries from node modules any more (e.g. RouteConfig or OnInit)

any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been using Intellij (15.x, now 2016.1) with ng2 since alpha-20 or so, and frankly it's been an inconsistent pain in the ass all along, specifically with respect to auto import, code completion, and refactoring.  2016.1 was a significant improvement, but there's still a long way to go - assuming I haven't been getting something wrong in the setup all along.

Comment: ive got it working again by copying my source and other relevant files into another projects folder where auto import was working...just wondering where the settings for this is...

Comment: In settings -> languages & frameworks -> typescript, there's a "scope" field there that I think is the key, but I haven't found good documentation on how to use it, and my experiments with it haven't helped much. There's also settings -> L&F -> Javascript -> Libraries, and I'm unclear on how that should be used in conjunction with TS scope. If you'd rephrase your question to ask for a canonical explanation of these settings, IMO it'd be a very good question.

Comment: what do you mean by 'auto-importing libraries from node modules'? Errors like 'Cannot find module 'angular2/core''? This doesn't have anything to do with javascript libraries settings... You need to make sure that correspondin d.ts files exists and can be resolved either using tsconfig.json or with the ///<reference path> comments

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Language & Framework -> Javascript and add new library typed node-modules pointing to your node-modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Idea was using wrong tsconfig.json (src/tsconfig.json) file. You can see which tsconfig.json is being used when the project is loaded to the IDE. After renaming src/tsconfig.json to src/tsconfig.json_disabled it started to use tsconfig.json from the root of the project. At this point, Idea didn't compile anything under src, because it was excluded in the tsconfig.json. I commented out the exclusion and everything started to work.

Although not perfect solution, the problems seems to be caused by wrong tsconfig.json. Unfortunately you cannot specify which tsconfig.json is used in project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what was the issue but I did this and it started working again

1. Make a copy of the app folder using finder/explorer
2. Delete `.idea` and `node_modules` folders from finder/explorer
3. Open the folder in webstorm and do `npm install`
4. Wait for webstorm to index all files.

It started working